# Android Issue with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, this

I'm facing some issues with the Intent method, and my app stops working when I'm clicking on the connexion Button. The fact is `Intent Welcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class)` doesn't work, i've an error with it :/

Here are the code of my MainActivity :

```
package black_beard_studio.smartschool;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Main_Content> Main_content;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ImageButton ConnectButton;
    EditText iden_text, pass_text;

    EditText Welcome;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Main_content = new ArrayList<>(); //Déclaration de la liste Main_content ou se trouveront les éléments de notre menu

        findViewById();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initDrawerLayout();


        ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (iden_text.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                        pass_text.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vérification des données...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent Welcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
                    Welcome.putExtra("iden_text", iden_text.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(Welcome);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Identifiants incorrects", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }




        } );



    }

    private void findViewById() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ConnectButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        iden_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        pass_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }



    private void initDrawerLayout() {
        setListViewData();
        setListViewHeader();
        //Mount listview with adapter
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, Main_content);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    private void setListViewHeader() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview, listView, false);
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    }

    private void setListViewData() { //Liste afficher dans le menu
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.id_small,"Carte ID", "Nom Random"));
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.note_small, "Relevé de note", "Note"));
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.calendar, "Calendrier", "Jours"));
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.souper, "Menu Cantine", "Jours"));
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.abs, "Absences & Retard", "Jours"));
        Main_content.add(new Main_Content(R.mipmap.disconnect, "Déconnexion", "OUI"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Replace fragment to Main layout
     * @param Main_content
     */
    public void updateMainLayout(Main_Content Main_content) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.container, ContentFragment.newInstance(Main_content));
        transaction.commit();

        //Ferme la navigation une fois que le fragment a été remplacé.
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
}
```

The code of my Welcome.class

```
public class Welcome extends  Activity  {

TextView tvView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);


    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeiD);

    Intent Welcome = getIntent();

    String Name = Welcome.getStringExtra("iden_text");

    tvView.setText("Bienvenue " +Name);



    }
}
```

I've already test with MainActivity.this, welcome.class, but it doesn't work too.
Here are somme screen too :

[image: Application running]
[image: Application stop running]

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: Instead of "this" try changing it to "YourActivity.this"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Intent Welcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
```

To:

```
Intent Welcome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
```

When referencing 'this' in the context you are, you are referring to View.OnClickListener which isn't valid as a context type. You will need to reference host activity which in this case appears to be MainActivity.

Comment: Could you expand on why it doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: You haven't applied the change in that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

By following line

```
Intent Welcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
```

word `this` does not reffer to `MainActivity`, it reffers to `View.OnClickListener` for your `ConnectButton`. First parameter for `Intent` is `Context` (which can be get from activity), not `View.OnClickListener`. This is the reason why you get error.

You should change it to the following line:

```
Intent Welcome = new Intent(MainActivity.class, Welcome.class);
```

Comment: 'this' does not refer to ConnectButton in this context, it refers to an anonymous View.OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

If it is "ActivityNotFoundException", you probably didn't add your activity in the manifest file.

Comment: No I've this error :  http://imgur.com/b6W8SA2   I tried to replace by MainActivity.this or .class , but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to declare the activity in android manifest file, sorry about that guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the below code:

```
Intent welcome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
```

Please note that Welcome is a class in your package, so use appropriate syntax for Intent object , use small letters, welcome instead of Welcome
Or try

```
Intent welcome = new Intent(this.getCallingActivity(), Welcome.class);
```

And declare in manifest file
Thanks
Sanjeeb